# For Loop Enumerate vs dict on enumerate

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, enumerate

Let me preface this question by stating that I am a novice both in Python and programming in general. That said, I was wondering whether there is any difference between the following two ways of creating a dictionary based on an existing list:

```
index = {}
seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for a,b in enumerate(seq): 
    index[a]= b
print(index)
print(dict(enumerate(seq)))
```

Output:

```
>>> print(index)
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
>>> print(dict(enumerate(seq)))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

Both "print (index)" and "print (dict (enumerate (seq)" yield an equivalent result and I was wondering which one is better to perform in this context. I stumbled upon the latter by just practicing some coding and it made me question why one would need to perform a for loop if a one-line code such as the dict() gives the same result.

Comment: Please indent your code in the question the same as the code that you are running.

Comment: As you wrote yourself, there is no reason to write a loop.

Comment: The `print` isn't really relevant. You could write `index = dict(enumerate(seq))` as a more concise alternative to a full `for` loop.

Comment: This turned out to be an interesting question. Points from me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a lot of one line loops. It's just used as maybe a more compiled way of defining something but a for loop is just as good in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no semantic difference. This

```
dict(enumerate(seq))
```

will execute faster.

**Update:** well, it seems that faster might not be as clear cut as I expected.. (or correct, except maybe for 3.9b1 - see @Bharel's answer).

*Update2:* I've added measurements for the dict comprehension solution from @ShadowRanger for completeness.

Py2.7:

```
(dev) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "dict(enumerate(seq))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 usec per loop

(dev) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "index = {}" "for a,b in enumerate(seq):" "  index[a]= b"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.686 usec per loop

(dev) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "{a: b for a,b in enumerate(seq)}"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.807 usec per loop
```

Py3.5:

```
(dev35) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "dict(enumerate(seq))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 usec per loop

(dev35) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "index = {}" "for a,b in enumerate(seq):" "  index[a]= b"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.813 usec per loop

(dev35) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "{a: b for a,b in enumerate(seq)}"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.917 usec per loop
```

Py3.8:

```
(dev38) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "dict(enumerate(seq))"
500000 loops, best of 5: 755 nsec per loop

(dev38) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "index = {}" "for a,b in enumerate(seq):" "  index[a]= b"
500000 loops, best of 5: 703 nsec per loop

(dev38) c:\srv> python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "{a: b for a,b in enumerate(seq)}"
500000 loops, best of 5: 879 nsec per loop
```

**Update 3:** @Bharel and @ShadowRanger has pointed out, the length of the list is important. With lists of ~10 items, the `dict(enumerate(..))` version becomes more performant.

code:

```
call workon dev
python -m timeit -s "seq = 'abcdefghij'" "dict(enumerate(seq))"
python -m timeit -s "seq = 'abcdefghij'" "index = {}" "for a,b in enumerate(seq):" "  index[a]= b"

call workon dev35
python -m timeit -s "seq = 'abcdefghij'" "dict(enumerate(seq))"
python -m timeit -s "seq = 'abcdefghij'" "index = {}" "for a,b in enumerate(seq):" "  index[a]= b"

call workon dev38
python -m timeit -s "seq = 'abcdefghij'" "dict(enumerate(seq))"
python -m timeit -s "seq = 'abcdefghij'" "index = {}" "for a,b in enumerate(seq):" "  index[a]= b"
```

output:

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.94 usec per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 usec per loop

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 usec per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 usec per loop

200000 loops, best of 5: 1.29 usec per loop
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.66 usec per loop
```

Comment: mate, you're creating the dict at setup. You're using the same dict again and again on your first test, while creating a dict each time at the second. These tests aren't equal.

Comment: @Bharel ah, thanks. Running your code, I still get that the for-loop is faster for 2.7, 3.5, 3.8.

Comment: @thebjorn: Update the tests for a moderate number of items; for 50ish items, `dict(enumerate(seq))` should win (not by enough to matter, but still by a meaningful margin). With only three, the fixed overhead is swamping the actual work.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm sure it's dependent on the machine, but on mine it only takes about 10'ish elements...

Comment: @thebjorn: I didn't actually time it this time, I've just done this before and gave a number large enough to definitely show the effect. 10 does not surprise me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference at all in the output.

Regarding timing, you may use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module to test for speed.

The second option, of one lining will necessarily be faster, and is also more readable in my opinion.

Timing results, Python 3.9:

```
python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "index = {}" "for a,b in enumerate(seq):" "  index[a]= b"
500000 loops, best of 5: 803 nsec per loop

python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']" "dict(enumerate(seq))"
500000 loops, best of 5: 786 nsec per loop
```

You might not see the difference in here, because the `dict()` operation for dict creation is longer than `{}`, and it's a fixed "setup cost".

If you'll increase the numbers to offset this "setup cost", you'll see the huge difference:

```
python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']*1000" "dict(enumerate(seq))"
500 loops, best of 5: 395 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']*1000" "index = {}" "for a,b in enumerate(seq):" "  index[a]= b"
500 loops, best of 5: 509 usec per loop
```

Comment: which python version?

Comment: @thebjorn 3.9b1. For some reason it feels like the gap is smaller than I expected. Doesn't it? I haven't compiled this one. It's a pure build from pyorg

Comment: on 3.5 I'm getting that the for-loop is faster... I'm double checking my results now...

Comment: @thebjorn remember that the dict is not part of the setup. Oh and `dict()` does require a LOAD_GLOBAL & func call instead of pure opcode. Maybe that's the reason for the smaller diff? I bet it'll be much larger at larger numbers.

Comment: The setup isn't measured, so that should be inconsequential.

Comment: Fist option is faster for me on python 3.7.3. The first option, 1000000 loops, best of 5: 301 nsec per loop. The second option, 1000000 loops, best of 5: 321 nsec per loop

Comment: Again guys, dict creation is not part of the setup. Don't do `index = {}` at setup.
Besides, if you'll increase the timing, the difference will rise.

Comment: I'm not doing dict creation, still get that the for loop is faster on 2.7, 3.5, 3.8.

Comment: The gap is small because the data is tiny. It's not really a relevant profile, things like function call overhead begin to dominate.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga they're doing a dict creation at setup.

Answer (score 0):

`dict(enumerate(seq))` is strictly better on performance and simplicity, it's just less flexible. For more flexibility, you'd go with `dict` comprehensions typically, e.g.:

```
index = {i: x * 2 for i, x in enumerate(seq)}  # Repeats each value
```

only going to your original `for` loop when the conversion code is too complicated for a comprehension.

Comment: well.. surprisingly, it doesn't seem to be faster...

Comment: @thebjorn: It's slightly faster for larger inputs. For small inputs, the minor fixed overhead of going through generic function dispatch to invoke the `dict` constructor can make it ever-so-slighty slower.